# Why is `HrmpChannelAccepted` described as only being safe to originate from a relay chain and not a parachain?

Tags: xcm, hrmp

I am reading through this section of XCM Instructions : https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/97930a8b2cc211ecfb80f289c4c578a9157e6dc4/xcm/src/v2/mod.rs#L532-L565
And what I find here is that both `HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest` & `HrmpChannelAccepted` have comments saying that these messages *must* or rather are only *safe* when originated on a relay chain. I am not familiar with HRMP channels so can someone explain to me, why should both of these messages be relay-chain origin only?

My understanding is that a channel open request could be sent by either the parachain or the relay chain, and `HrmpChannelAccepted` should be a message to acknowledge the aforementioned request. So what is different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HRMP](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-xcm-transport#hrmp-xcmp-lite) is a stop-gap protocol for XCMP, it stores all messages in the Relay Chain storage.
Before the channel is opened, the two parachains are not interoperable, and can only establish a connection with the VMP through the relaychain.

When ParachainA wants to open a channel to ParachainB, ParachainA should send XCM `Transact(hrmpInitOpenChannel)` to relaychain, then the relaychain [send XCM `HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest` notification](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.40/runtime/parachains/src/hrmp.rs#L1200) to ParachainB via DMP. So the origin is relaychain.

When ParachainB wants to accept the channel request, ParachainB should send XCM `hrmpAcceptOpenChannel` to relaychain, then the relaychain [send XCM `HrmpChannelAccepted` notification](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.40/runtime/parachains/src/hrmp.rs#L1261) to ParachainA via DMP. So the origin is relaychain.